# Dyanamic drop-down insert the state name using laravel 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Hi i am using `dynamic drop down` for state and city, when i am selecting the state and city from drop-down after insertion state id is going into database I want insert state name instead of id. if i am removing id from in `(option value=id)` dynamic drop down is not working... please suggest me

This is My Blade Template:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{URL::to('test/insert')}}">  
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"/>
    <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control input-sm">
        @foreach($states $state)
            <option value="{{$state->id}}">{{$state->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <select id="city" class="form-control input-sm" name="city">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<script>
    $('#state').on('change',function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var state_id = e.target.value;
        $.get('city?state_id=' + state_id, function(data){
        $('#city').empty();
        $.each(data,function(index,subcatObj){
            $('#city').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.name+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is My controller:

```
public function state()
{
    $states=DB::table('states')->get();
    return View::make('index')->with('states',$states);
}

public function city()
{
    $state_id=Input::get('state_id');
    $cities=DB::table('towns')->where('state_id','=', $state_id )->get();
    return Response::json($cities);
}
```

This is my Insert states and city Controller:

```
public function insert() {
    $s_name=array('state'   => Input::get('state'),
                  'city'    => Input::get('city'));
    DB::table('test')->insert( $s_name);
}
```

Comment: Did you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can update your `select` to something like (i.e. add the data-id attribute):

```
@foreach($states $state)
    <option value="{{$state->name}}" data-id="{{$state->id}}">{{$state->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Then, update your JavaScript function to (i.e. pick up the new `data-id` attribute to get the cities from ajax):

```
$('#state').on('change',function(e){
    console.log(e);
    var state_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.get('city?state_id=' + state_id, function(data){
    $('#city').empty();
        $.each(data,function(index,subcatObj){
            $('#city').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.name+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>');
        });
    });
});
```

Then, submitting the form should give you the name of the state rather than the ID.

Comment: How about dependent dropdown?

Comment: You should ask a new question detailing your specific use case and showing your code so far.

Comment: This question is more specific and more important for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65454848/laravel-nested-foreach-by-2-different-model-in-view please solve this problem