# Laravel Nested @foreach By 2 Different Model in View

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**Model**

```
// Relationship in \App\FatherRegistrars and \App\MotherRegistrars and \App\GuardianMaleRegistrars \App\GuardianFemaleRegistrars
public function student_registrars()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\StudentRegistrars')->withTrashed();
}
```

[image]
**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $dataFathers = \App\FatherRegistrars::get();
    $dataMothers = \App\MotherRegistrars::get();

    $dataGM = \App\GuardianMaleRegistrars::get();
    $dataGF = \App\GuardianFemaleRegistrars::get();

    // manual pagination using code attached in AppServiceProvider.php
    $data = $dataFathers->toBase()->merge($dataMothers)->paginate($items);

    return view('parents-guardians-registrars.index', compact('data', 'dataFathers', 'dataMothers', 'dataGM', 'dataGF'))->withItems($items); 
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($data as $var)
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="sub_chk" data-id="{{$var->id}}" value="{{$var->id}}" name="selected_values[]"/>
        </td>
        <td>{{$var->id }}</td>
        <td>{{$var->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$var->email}}</td>
        <td> 
          <?php $elements = array(); ?>
          @foreach($var->student_registrars as $category)
            <?php $elements[] = '<a href=" '.route('student-registrars.show', $category->id).' "> '.$category->name.' </a>'; ?>
          @endforeach
          <?php echo implode(',<br>', $elements); ?>
        </td> 
        <td>
          // Second foreach should be here
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="{{ route('father-registrars.show', $var->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Detail</a>
        </td>
    @endforeach 

    // Second foreach
    @foreach($dataGM as $var2)
    <tr>
       <td>
         <?php $elements = array(); ?>
         @foreach($var2->student_registrars as $category)
            <?php $elements[] = '<a href=" '.route('student-registrars.show', $category->id).' "> '.$category->name.' </a>'; ?>
         @endforeach
         <?php echo implode(',<br>', $elements); ?>
       </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach 

      </tr>
```

And the result for code above is:
[image]

I have a little problem related multiple foreach in one view. It's actually just a simple problem but I am stuck here. Any body can solve it?
Should I use partial view to do this?

Comment: With each `<tr>` a new table line starts.  I do think you have too much `<tr>` elements.

Comment: I remove `<tr>` inside second foreach, but the result is not as expected

Comment: You can see the picture I've attached above. There is a description in there. That's what I want.

Comment: This is likely an issue with the data rather than the HTML. Please add your PHP code to the questionnaire so we can see how the two arrays are generated.

Comment: @NirajShah I've updated the code. Please check it!

Answer (score 0):

This may not exactly work (not tested or verified), but you can give something like this a try:

```
@foreach($data as $var)
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="sub_chk" data-id="{{$var->id}}" value="{{$var->id}}" name="selected_values[]"/>
    </td>
    <td>{{$var->id }}</td>
    <td>{{$var->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$var->email}}</td>

    <?php $elements = array(); ?>
    @foreach($var->student_registrars as $i => $category)
      <td> 
        <?php $elements[] = '<a href=" '.route('student-registrars.show', $category->id).' "> '.$category->name.' </a>'; ?>
        <?php echo implode(',<br>', $elements); ?>
      </td> 
      <td>
          <?php $elements2 = array(); ?>
         @foreach($var2->student_registrars[$i] as $category)
            <?php $elements2[] = '<a href=" '.route('student-registrars.show', $category->id).' "> '.$category->name.' </a>'; ?>
         @endforeach
         <?php echo implode(',<br>', $elements2); ?>
      </td>
    @endforeach
    
    <td>
      <a href="{{ route('father-registrars.show', $var->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Detail</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

The problem you have is that there is no direct association `$data` and `$dataGM`. You should try and use Relationships so that the data needed for `$dataGM` can be accessed as a relationship from `$data`, e.g.

```
$children = $data[$i]->children;
$adopted = $data[$i]->adopted_children;
```

Then you can loop directly on these items instead of having to create multiple variables.

Comment: The result for your solution gives us  `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`. Also, I've updated the code, please check it!